# A project with an Output Type of class library cannot be started directly - Tried previous solutions

Tags: c#, .net-5

I am trying to get around this error. Now I have researched this problem as it shows many people have had this problem but I cannot still get it working

my project has 4 parts.

```
 Name.Core
 Name.Data
 Name.Test
 Name.Web
```

This is what I have done so far.

- I have right-clicked on my solution (4/4) project and I have clicked startup project.
- I then have clicked on the single startup project (drop-down box NameOfMysolution.data) and moved forward. This did not work.
- I then did the same thing and have clicked on the current selection (clicked on the single startup project, and then-current project and applied it) - This did not work either.
- I then right-clicked my solution and did properties and hit multiple startup projects, applied, and then applied it. - Nothing runs
- I then right-clicked my solution and did properties and hit multiple startup projects and then where it lists project and actions, I have then used the action and switched none to start (all of them), and then applied it.
- Then these two problems have shown up.

> The program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an
> entry point  MSB3030  Could not copy the file "C:etc/
> PatientHut.Core.runtimeconfig.json" because it was not found.
> "C:etc/PatientHut.Core\bin\Debug\net5.0\PatientHut.Core.runtimeconfig.dev.json"
> because
> it was not found. SolutionName.Test  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    4964

I believe this is showing because I ran them all together.

I then cleaned the solution and right clicked again, single start-up and then ran it, and the two errors show:

> The program does not contain a static Main method suitable for an
> entry point
> 'C:SolutionName.Core\bin\Debug\net5.0\ref\SolutionName.Core.dll' could
> not be found SolutionName.Data  C:SolutionName.Data\CSC   1   Active

I have looked online, and I keep trying to solve this issue and I keep running into problems. I have no idea why this is not working!

Can someone please help me, and explain this in the simplest way possible? (I have looked previously at other posts on this).

Comment: A little bit TLDR; above... did you right click on your `Name.web` project in the solution explorer, then select `Set as start up project`?

Comment: @slugster I am sorry I written a very long question. Usually when I ask a question and it is too short I get people that vote it down as they assume I have not researched this issue too well. I am a beginner coder!  Slugster, I really like to thank you it seemed to work by just doing that! It has went to local hot to display my site, but the site is not loading and the db is created too! - Although I will be posting another question about this soon on my db. I really like to thank you again Slugster - This has really helped